# get a node under a xsi:type in xml in c#

Tags: c#, system.xml

I have an XML file with the format below

```
<ScriptElement>
      <ElementData xsi:type="FirstElement">
         .......
         .......
         .......
         <Description></Description>
         ........ 
      </ElementData>
</ScriptElement>
<ScriptElement>
      <ElementData xsi:type="SecondElement">
         .......
         .......
         .......
         <Description></Description>
         ........ 
      </ElementData>
</ScriptElement>
<ScriptElement>
      <ElementData xsi:type="ThirdElement">
         .......
         .......
         .......
         <Description></Description>
         ........ 
      </ElementData>
</ScriptElement>
```

I want to change the `InnerText` of the `Description Node` which is under the `xsi:type="SecondElement"`

When i try to get the attribute value of the namespace

```
string attrValist = Doc.SelectSingleNode("ScriptElements/ScriptElement/ElementData/@xsi:type").Value;

MessageBox.Show(attrValist);
```

Am getting an error as `"Namespace Manager or XsIContext needed. The query has a prefix variable or user-defined function"`

Could you please suggest me how should i move forward.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Xml Linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication50
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test2.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            Dictionary<string, XElement> dict = doc.Descendants("ElementData").GroupBy(x => (string)x.Attributes().Where(y => y.Name.LocalName == "type").FirstOrDefault(), z => z)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());

            XElement SecondElement = dict["SecondElement"];

            SecondElement.Element("Description").SetValue("abcd");
        }
    }


}
```